# .NET Core - CORS error even after enabling CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, angular5, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to call the WebAPI method to get some data, but it throws a `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://localhost:44332/api/Controller/Action with MIME type text/html.` even though I have enabled CORS in my ConfigureServices Method and used the policy in the Configure method in the startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            .....
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });


}
```

What could the reason be?

Comment: Is the port correct in http://localhost:4200/? try changing the port to 44332

Comment: Sometimes when a 500 happens an ajax call will still experience a cors error.

Comment: The error indicates a request for `text/html`.  Should it be some other content type?

Comment: @CRice is correct, this is probably happening because you are getting an error before you handle cors, perhaps you're missing a registration from your Depency injection container?

Comment: @AmanB The port is correct

Comment: @CRice was right, an exception thrown was being masked as a CORS Error. Wierd though

Answer (score 1):

So, Basically as CRice and johnny commented, `Internal server error` are propagated as CORS Error.

Since it is good practice to handle all errors within the application, doing so will make sure `500 Internal Server Error` will be intact even in the case of an exception and not be masked as CORS Error.

It can be understood better [here](https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/90)

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

Note: The URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is returned.